# Display a WEBM video in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video, webm

Currently I'm using AVPlayer in my iOS app for playing videos. But when I try to load a file in webm format I get the error : `format no supported`.

Whats the best way to add webm support to my app?

I have checked [OGVKit](https://github.com/brion/OGVKit) @ github but it is still in beta version.

I also considered to user a webview, but I'm not an iOS expert and I don't know if it is a good idea or it can result in other problems like different versions of webview depending in the OS version, etc.

How can I solve that?

Comment: A webm won't play in a webview either.

Comment: Check out https://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit/ for the VLCKit library for iOS, it should support WebM. I had the same issue and what I ended up doing is forking the OGVKit library and modifying to work for me. If you have standard videos with audio tracks you should be able to use the OGVKit out of the box via cocoapods

Comment: can you hare OGVKit's working format? Downloaded kit is not even building successfully.